# Returning form results in a separate div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

So I want to return a user's form results in a div so they can see what they have chosen underneath the form using JQuery but struggling to use the right code? Ive tried using the .html function and replaceWith. etc but nothing seems to be working?

Here's my html code:

```
<form id="myform">
    <h4>Enter your booking slot here:</h4><br>
    <select id="programmes">
        <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="test3">Test 3</option>
        <option value="test4">Test 4</option>
        <option value="test5">Test 5</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <select id="time">
        <option value="one">01:00</option>
        <option value="two">02:00</option>
        <option value="three">03:00</option>
        <option value="four">04:00</option>
        <option value="five">05:00</option>
        <option value="six">06:00</option>
        <option value="seven">07:00</option>
        <option value="eight">08:00</option>
        <option value="nine">09:00</option>
        <option value="ten">10:00</option>
        <option value="eleven">11:00</option>
        <option value="twevle">12:00</option>
        <option value="one-pm">13:00</option>
        <option value="two-pm">14:00</option>
        <option value="three-pm">15:00</option>
        <option value="four-pm">16:00</option>
        <option value="five-pm">17:00</option>
        <option value="six-pm">18:00</option>
        <option value="seven-pm">19:00</option>
        <option value="eight-pm">20:00</option>
        <option value="nine-pm">21:00</option>
        <option value="ten-pm">22:00</option>
        <option value="eleven-pm">23:00</option>
        <option value="midnight">00:00</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit Booking">
</form>
</div>

<div></div>
```

Comment: You should paste your code into the description instead of using an image. Makes it easier to copy and paste :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#select').on('change', function() {
  $('#result').html( $(this).find('option:selected').text() )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="test_1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="test_2">Test 2</option>
  <option value="test_3">Test 3</option>
  <option value="test_4">Test 4</option>
  <option value="test_5">Test 5</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: where would I put the jquery? As it doesnt work when I put this in separate tags under the html

Comment: should work fine if your jquery included *after* the HTML